# Best way to create a file that acts as a checksum and verifies the sender?

Tags: python, encryption, hash, sha256, pki

I'm looking to send a file to multiple people, but I also want them to know that:

1. The file has not been changed since I sent it to them.
2. They know that it was me who sent the file.

I'm coding in Python, so I was thinking of pulling in the file, taking a hash of it, and then encrypting the hash with my private key. I would send the original file along with this new file (probably just a .txt) to whoever I want. My friends could then decrypt the hash using my public key and compare it to a hash they take of the original file. I'd like to use something at least on the level of SHA-256. I do not want to use MD5 or SHA-1.

Note- The original file I am sending does not have to be encrypted, just looking for some integrity and non-repudiation.

Would this fulfill the two requirements above? And is there an easy way to implement this in Python?

Comment: I would recommend using an existing encryption solution. For example, PGP. You can interface with PGP via Python of course. (https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/)

Comment: How are you going to send the file? E-mail? Many email clients already have cryptographic signatures as a built-in feature.

Comment: You are reinventing cryptographic signature. If you used GPG for example, you can do `gpg --sign myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of pulling in the file, taking a hash of it, and then encrypting the hash with my private key

That's exactly what we commonly call *signing* or *digital-signature*, which fulfills your two requirements.

> Would this fulfill the two requirements above?

Yes. Signing a message doesn't prevent it from being manipulated. It's only getting *infeasible* of generating a signature for a manipulated message without the private key.

> And is there an easy way to implement this in Python?

Sure, [pyCrypto](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto) supports RSA and DSA. You should try [ed25519](https://github.com/warner/python-ed25519), though, because its signatures are smaller.